# What is the probability someone is dealt three of a kind in this version of cards?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider a game that consists of dealing out three hands of three cards each from a deck of nine cards. The deck contains the three Aces, three Kings, and three Queens. What is the probability someone is dealt three of a kind?

Attempt: Let D= event 3 of a kind are dealt to someone.

Then there are (9 choose 3 ways set the cards in each deck x 3 choose 1 ways to pick a deck)

(9 choose 1 * 2 choose 2 ways to pick the other two cards)

I'm confused now though. I don't understand the logic

Comment: First, let's get clear on the question: Is it the chance of *exactly* one person getting three of a kind, or *at least* one?

Comment: @Bram28 I have no idea the question doesn't specify. It just says someone. I'm thinking it means at least one

Comment: OK, that would be my interpretation as well. Now, one trick with a question like that is to calculate the chance of *no one* getting three of a kind ... for then you can just subtract that probability form 1 to get the probability of at least one person getting three of a kind.  By the way: is it possible for exactly two people to get three of a kind?

Comment: No that is impossible. But the problem is, there are (9 choose 1 ways to pick card one and 6 choose 2 ways to pick card two and three) then you multiply this by 3 choose one. But This number is larger than 9 choose 3 x 3 choose 1 total possible combos I came up with? I don't understand where I'm going wrong

Comment: Not following your calculations. Yes, there are 9 cards, so 9 ways to choose card 1 ... but where does the 6 choose 2 come from?  What, in fact, are you trying to calculate here?

Comment: @Bram28 Since there are 3 of each type of card so if we want to not have 3 of a kind we need to not use anymore of the first type of card we chose. I'm trying to calculate the probability no one gets 3 of a kind.

Comment: OK, that makes sense ... but that is just for person 1. Now you also need to look at what person 2 gets.  Likewise for your *total* number of ways: 9 choose 3 is only the different hands person 1 can get, but you need to multiply this by 6 choose 3 for person 2.

Comment: Abother thing is that when you multiply 9 by 6 choose 2 for person 1 ... you are saying that that first card is a special card (e.g. person 1 would paste it on their forehead, for example), while the other 2 come as a unordered set. ... You need to think about unordered sets the whole way through

Answer (score 1):

Total number of hands is $\begin{pmatrix} 9 \\3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\3\end{pmatrix}$.

Number of hands where person 1 gets 3 of a kind is $3\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\3\end{pmatrix}$. Similarly for the other two players.

Number of hands where each person gets 3 of a kind is $3!$.

The probability is $$\frac{3(3\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\3\end{pmatrix}-3!)+3!}{\begin{pmatrix} 9 \\3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\3\end{pmatrix}}=\frac{9\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\3\end{pmatrix}-12}{\begin{pmatrix} 9 \\3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\3\end{pmatrix}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll use counting where....... $$P = \frac{\text{successful outcomes}}{\text{total outcomes}}$$

$$P = \frac{3\cdot \binom{6}{3}+2\cdot 3 (\binom{6}{3} - 2)}{\binom{9}{3}\cdot \binom{6}{3}} = \frac{60 + 108}{84\cdot 20} = \frac{1}{10}$$